# Old Animated sci-fi film - late 70s

Tags: story-identification, animation

Help! Going a little mad trying to track down a film I saw when I was young.

A few things in the film stand out for me:

The male protagonist is some sort of ships pilot, who lands on a planet and drives around for a bit in a vehicle that is on stilts and has wheels on the end. It crashes into a boulder and he's reduced to carrying on on foot.

He encounters a man (or robot) in a crater, whose job it is is to push metal scrap boulders into holes. I think the pilot jumps into one of these holes and follows the tunnel. The tunnel ends at the top of a mountain where the boulder that has been pushed down rolls down into the crater, for the cycle of pushing to start again.

I watched it on the television twice - late 70s and again in the early 80s.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: This sounds like someone might be referencing Sisyphus with the boulders, but no dice adding that to the search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a chapter in the French-Japanese anime *[Ulysses 31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_31)* called "The Eternal Punishment" in which the storyline is very similar.

The character in that chapter is called Sisyphus too. The same reference to the classic myth.

Comment: I was aware of Ulysses, but dismissed it as I thought the animation was a different style. Thanks for the answer though. will have to watch it on YouTube now and verify.

Comment: I had a chance to watch it and it's definately that. However, Not sure about the reference to the vehicle that was on stilts and it craching.